# Volume of intersections of spherical caps

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, volume, spheres

Suppose we have a unit sphere $\mathcal{S}^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, and for $\mathbf{u} \in \mathcal{S}^{d-1}$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, define $$\mathcal{C}_{\mathbf{u},\alpha} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S}^{d-1}: \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{u} \rangle \geq \alpha\} \subset \mathcal{S}^{d-1}.$$
I wish to compute the following quantities *exactly*, for small $k = 3, 4, 5, \dots$, where the input parameters are $\alpha$ and $\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\textrm{vol}(\mathcal{C}_{\mathbf{u},\alpha})}{\textrm{vol}(\mathcal{S}^{d-1})} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\textrm{vol}(\mathcal{C}_{\mathbf{u},\alpha} \cap \mathcal{C}_{\mathbf{v},\alpha})}{\textrm{vol}(\mathcal{S}^{d-1})} \, .
\end{align}
Are there any nice, exact formulas to work with here? I suppose ''unsolvable'' integrals without closed-form expression are inevitable, so perhaps some easy-to-evaluate formula to feed to mathematics software that allows me to get good, accurate numerical estimates of these quantities quickly?

Comment: You realize that unless $u = v$, the volume of the intersection of the caps is zero (because that intersection is codomension 1 in $S^{d-1}$).  Or did you intend to use incoherent volumes in your second form?  (By incoherent, I mean "having incompatible dimensions, so meaningless".)

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure I follow. If I take the circle in two dimensions, and ask for dot product greater than 1/3 with (1,0) and greater than 1/3 with (0,1), I get a non-negligible part of the circle with non-negligible volume.

Comment: (If it helps, by "volume" I mean the Haar measure on the unit sphere, and the ratio of volumes can equivalently be stated as the probability that a uniformly random vector from the unit sphere lies in the given region.)

Comment: You get two circular arcs whose intersection is zero, one, or two points (because I'm too lazy to draw the diagram), having *length* zero.

Comment: @Eric The spherical cap is defined as having inner product *at least* $\alpha$, not *exactly* $\alpha$, and thus the intersection **does not** have length zero. Draw the diagram and you'll see.

Comment: Your $S^{d-1}$ has dimension at least $1$ less than the ambient space.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, this means your $\mathcal{C}$ is an arc of a circle (or one or two points), not a segment.  Unless the two $\mathcal{C}$s have the same center the intersection of two of them is either zero, one, or two points.  (If the centers are the same the intersection is either empty or an arc of a circle.)  In each case the dimensionality of the intersection is at most one less than that of the denominator in your ratios.